# Jenkins pipeline one parameter like array or something to pass the list of services in a one order

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

In jenkins as a parameterized build I have to pass the list of services in a one order for e.g. app-config, app-core, app-ui and so on as a one parameter like array or something I can pass list of services to the jenkins pipeline.

I have multiple micro-services on a repository, and I want to pass the array or something to build the one and more services. like we have ten micro-services and I pass the four services names then it will build all four services.

as of now nothing tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/
Just look at the multiple select examples.

Comment: I don't want to use active choice plugin; can we do it through multiline parameters-based job?